# how to write sql query for getting primary key in a query where aggregate functions are used

Tags: sql-server

My table structure looks like this:

[image]

I want id(primary key) of city with max population **statewise**.

If there is a tie in max population in particular state then any one id of those rows should be selected.

[image]

Comment: Show the output you want from this.

Comment: There is answer already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window function for this:

```
with cte as(select *, row_number() 
                      over(partition by state order by population desc, id) rn from table)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

If there can be several rows with max population then you can try `rank` function instead of `row_number`:

```
with cte as(select *, rank() 
                      over(partition by state order by population desc) rn from table)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

Comment: What will it do if there are two Ids (4 & 5), let's say, with max population for same state?

Comment: @Zane, with first version it will output only 4. With second version it will output both.

Answer (score 1):

required sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY population DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM dbo.tbl_city
    ) s
WHERE s.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, state, population
from tbl_city a
where id = (select top 1 id from tbl_city where state = a.state order by population DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT id, state, population,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY state ORDER BY population DESC) AS rn
   FROM tbl_city) AS A
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT id,
       state,
       population
FROM   #yourtable A
WHERE  population IN(SELECT Max(population) AS population
                     FROM   #yourtable A1
                     WHERE  A.state = A1.state
                     GROUP  BY state)
```